# Snackbar is not working within fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-design-library, android-snackbar

I am trying to show **snackbar** view when I click on button but it shows force close error when I click on button

I have define fragment class below and also error log.

I have fragment class:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
        initUI(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void initUI(View view) {

        btn= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnpress);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(getView(),"SnackBAr Test" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**fragment_home.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainrl"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp" >

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:Text="PLEASE PRESS" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I press on button it is not showing `snackbar`. it gives below error log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.findSuitableParent(Snackbar.java:237)
            at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:206)
            at com.example.test.fragment.HomeFragment$3.onLeftCardExit(HomeFragment.java:168)
            at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener.onAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:1030)
            at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1056)
            at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$400(ValueAnimator.java:50)
            at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:644)
            at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:660)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solved this error?

Comment: Have you tried it by passing `v` instead of `getView` as first parameter?

Comment: What is v ? i have tried by passing `view` instead of `getView` but it is not working. same error.

Comment: mean `onClick(View v) ` method parameter

Comment: Yes i have tried that also But still get the force close error.

Comment: `at com.example.test.fragment.HomeFragment$3.onLeftCardExit(HomeFragment.java:168)` please show this method code..

Comment: @Kushal updated code.Please check it

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have solved this:

It is fine if we do not include `CoordinatedLayout` to my `fragment_home.xml`

Solution:

Defined :
private RelativeLayout mRoot;

Now initialize in `initUI(View view)`

```
mRoot = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainrl);
```

and on Button click event put the following code:

```
 Snackbar.make(mRoot, "Had a snack at Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Now main thing about this is:

just change current theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

It Done.!!!

Comment: If someone else here with not showing Snackbar, check you wrote `.show()` method after it! It's stupid, but it was the case for me

Comment: @Nexen I love you. And yes, it's stupid but is has happened twice in a month to me.

Comment: This solution doesn't pop up the layout

Answer (score 105):

You can also use:

```
getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

like this:

```
Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
           "Look at me, I'm a fancy snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackBar.show();
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486034/get-root-view-from-current-activity/4488149#4488149)

Comment: Oh Man! you saved my whole __Clan__ from _huge_ destruction, in the end your answer works

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu I'm using a similar approach. But it gives me error. `Cannot resolve method getActivity()` Why ?

Comment: @Omid1989 Add the line of code where you are using it as a comment here

Comment: Can this be used blindly everywhere wherever I want to show a `Snackbar`? Because this root view will be available within all activities and fragments.

Comment: For me, if I have a fragment inside an activity I can get the fragment's container view and ir works fine. However, If I am in fragment that is inside a tablayout it does not working by getting the fragments container. Then, I have to use this approach or get the activity's container.

Answer (score 7):

SnackBar `make` method takes a view and from that view it trails up the heirarchy until it finds a suitable layout to show, if you had an exception this means that you didn't add CoordinatedLayout to your project

```
private static ViewGroup findSuitableParent(View view) {
        ViewGroup fallback = null;

        do {
            if(view instanceof CoordinatorLayout) {
                return (ViewGroup)view;
            }

            if(view instanceof FrameLayout) {
                // android.R.id.content
                if(view.getId() == 16908290) {
                    return (ViewGroup)view;
                }

                fallback = (ViewGroup)view;
            }

            if(view != null) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                view = parent instanceof View?(View)parent:null;
            }
        } while(view != null);

        return fallback;
    }
```

Comment: So i just have to write this code into current fragment class ?

Comment: and what if i dont want to add coordinatedLayout ?

Comment: no, this is built in to SnackBar, you are probably not adding something to your dependencies

Comment: @deepak, if you want to use the Android snackbar, you must add everything related to it as well

Comment: i have added `android-support-design.JAR` in my code.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin language you have to use:

```
requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.context_id)
```

For example:

```kotlin
Snackbar.make(
    requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.context_id),
    getString(R.string.something_went_wrong),
    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show()
```