# Firebase switch reading error when I update data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble reading the status of a boolean from my firebase database into a switch I have .

I keep getting a null pointer exception but the value exists in the database so not sure what i have done incorrect

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference

Fragment

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_match_details_fragment, container, false);


    //FIREBASE
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final String uId = firebaseUser.getUid();

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    usersDatabase = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");
    groupsDatabase = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("groups");

    tvAddedBy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAddedByMatchDisplay);
    tvMatchTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMatchTime);
    tvMatchDay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMatchDay);
    switchPlaying = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switchPlay);

    btnConfirmStatus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayingConfirm);

    switchPlaying.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean playingExtra) {
            Snackbar.make(compoundButton, "Playing: " + playingExtra, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("ACTION", null).show();
        }
    });



    btnConfirmStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });



     readPlaying();


    return view;
}// end onCreate


// Read playing times from DB
private void readPlaying() {
    usersDatabase.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("playingExtra").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.exists() || dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                Boolean playingExtra = Boolean.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                switchPlaying.setChecked(playingExtra);

            }
        }
```

Full Stack Trace

```
05-08 15:57:00.461 2392-2601/com..squad E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8e53e40
05-08 15:57:01.046 2392-2392/com.ciaranbyrne.squad E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:192)
                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:224)
                                                                         at com.ciaranbyrne.squad.DisplayMatchFragment$1.onCheckedChanged(DisplayMatchFragment.java:97)
                                                                         at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:156)
                                                                         at android.widget.Switch.setChecked(Switch.java:1070)
                                                                         at com.ciaranbyrne.squad.DisplayMatchFragment$3.onDataChange(DisplayMatchFragment.java:134)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakp.zzcxi(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaks$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
05-08 15:57:15.694 2392-2601/com.ciaranbyrne.squad E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  Out of memory!
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: First of all, when posting a question about a crash, the complete stack trace helps to pinpoint exactly which line is at fault. Second of all, the error message means that at the line at fault, you are doing something like `<ViewGroup>.getContext()` but the `ViewGroup` is `null`, so I'm not sure Firebase has anything to do with it. Finally, only `dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);` is necessary if the value has been set with `reference.setValue(<true/false>);`

Comment: Added the stack trace as per suggestion, I just tried using Boolean playingExtra = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class); but no luck

Comment: Post your activity

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I am not too familiar with debugging in Android but after looking in the stack trace as per your suggestion it looks like it had something to with the SnackBar. 
Still learning, but thanks again for the tip

Comment: @Ciaránimo i made an edit, try now

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Playing: " + String.valueOf(playingExtra), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .setAction("ACTION", null).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `CoordinatorLayout` that looks like this:

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
```

Than to use the `Snackbar` class, please use the following code:

```
Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Playing: " + playingExtra, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("ACTION", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do what you want
        }
     }).show();
```

Also try to change that line with:

```
dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the details well enough to explain them, but there appear to be issues with creating a `SnackBar` in a `Fragment` before the fragment's view hierarchy has been added to the enclosing activity ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30569705/4815718)).

You need to perform the processing in `readPlaying()` at a later point in the [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).  Move it out of `onCreateView()` and into `onActivityCreated()` or some lifecycle method that executes later, such as `onStart()`.